# add_image_size in advance custom field image - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields, image-size

Ive made a custom image size in my functions.php file

```
add_image_size('blog_image', 417,300, true);
```

Then my code in the php file my image is showing

```
<?php $image=get_field("post_image");?>
style="background:url('<?php echo $image['url']['blog_image'];?>');"
```

If I take out the `['blog_image']` my image appears on the page(without scaling the image) but when its added there is no image

When I do a `var_dump` I get

```
array(10) {
    ["id"]=> int(672) 
    ["alt"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["title"]=> string(16) "google-maps-logo" 
    ["caption"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["description"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["mime_type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
    ["url"]=> string(70) "http://192.168.242.108/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/google-maps-logo.jpg" 
    ["width"]=> int(1024) 
    ["height"]=> int(1024) 

    ["sizes"]=> array(18) {

        ["thumbnail"]=> string(78) "http://192.168.242.108/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/google-maps-logo-150x150.jpg" 
        ["thumbnail-width"]=> int(150) 
        ["thumbnail-height"]=> int(150) 
        ["medium"]=> string(78) "http://192.168.242.108/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/google-maps-logo-300x300.jpg" 
        ["medium-width"]=> int(300) 
        ["medium-height"]=> int(300) 
        ["large"]=> string(70) "http://192.168.242.108/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/google-maps-logo.jpg" 
        ["large-width"]=> int(1024) 
        ["large-height"]=> int(1024) 
        ["home_box_image"]=> string(78) "http://192.168.242.108/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/google-maps-logo-480x320.jpg" 
        ["home_box_image-width"]=> int(480) 
        ["home_box_image-height"]=> int(320) 
        ["team_member"]=> string(78) "http://192.168.242.108/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/google-maps-logo-394x371.jpg" 
        ["team_member-width"]=> int(394) 
        ["team_member-height"]=> int(371) 
        ["blog_image"]=> string(79) "http://192.168.242.108/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/google-maps-logo-417x1000.jpg" 
        ["blog_image-width"]=> int(417) 
        ["blog_image-height"]=> int(1000) 
    } 
}
```

another `add_image_size(team_member)` works on another page where i use the feature image but i cant use the feature image for this part. This is the image that works

```
<img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachmentID, 'team_member')[0] ;?>"/>
```

Comment: What do you see when you `var_dump($image);`?

Comment: Theres quite a lot but theres this part with blog_image in

 ["blog_image"]=> string(79) "http://192.168.242.108/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/google-maps-logo-417x1000.jpg" ["blog_image-width"]=> int(417) ["blog_image-height"]=> int(1000) } }

Comment: Can you edit your question with the full output? Comments don't format nicely.

Comment: added the var_dump to the question

Comment: added an example of where an add_image_size works too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your `var_dump()` you're trying to access the URL incorrectly. It should be:

```
$image['sizes']['blog_image'];
```

Comment: Glad I could help! `var_dump()` is an extremely useful tool for discovering the contents of variables. Definitely add it to your tool set!

Comment: I know my boss keeps telling me to use it ha! I'm a bit of a newbie with CMS always been static before i worked here